# How to fix position of mat-select-panel in Angular Material

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a project in which I use Angular Material Components and I would like to customize mat-select. I want to achieve select input which mat-select-panel looks like it's dropdown as in native html select. I accomplished good effect using only CSS styles but I have one problem.

The problem is that my mat-select looks different depending on the size of the browser window. More specifically, mat-form-field and mat-select-panel sometimes are not aligned (there left sides are not in line) and this is not acceptable in my project.

This link is how it should look (example: Firefox browser, window size 100%):
[image: a link]

This link is what I want to fix(example: Firefox browser, window size 90%):
[image]

My predictions why it does not work:
mat-select-panel has a position absolute and is set to position depending on cdk-overlay-panel. Cdk-overlay-panel position is calculated dynamically. Sometimes fractional width and height values are truncated and hence the difference of one pixel between mat-form-field and mat-select-panel. This is an example:

[image]

What I want to achieve?
I am looking for a way to make my input always look good regardless of the browser window size. Line between mat-form-field and mat-select-panel must always be straight.

Stackblitz for my input is here:
[a link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-matselect-style-dwvyu8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Love the attention to detail in your observation... I've had a customer with such an eye also :) ... on [checking your stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-matselect-style-dwvyu8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), we observe the following which is a bigger issue which needs resolution:

[image]

**Commented your CSS** `.container>*{   position: absolute;   top: 30vh;   left: 30vw; }` **with the following** to observe the effect of mis-aligned few pixels on zooming in/out on the browser:

```
.myMatOptions{  position: absolute;  top: 30vh;  left: 30vw; }
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container{left: 30vw;}
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane { left:0 !important; transform:none !important;}
::ng-deep .mat-select-panel{left: 0}
```

on a zoom of **80%**, we see:
[image]

on a zoom of **90%**, we see a minor mis-alignment in the rendered output:
[image]

on a zoom of **100%**, we see:
[image]

on a zoom of **110%**, we see a minor mis-alignment in the rendered output:
[image]

on a zoom of **125%**, we see:
[image]

These minor visual issues (on 90% and 110%) are on the rendered output - the css behind these is exact so there is nothing fundamental to resolve. [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-matselect-style-bxlcsj)

Comment: Thanks but isn't work in my project. It works only in the example in Stackblitz. I use this select in more complex project. Maybe you know what I should do when my mat-form-field is located in MatDialog. Then left and top value is calculated dynamically. Styles with ::ng-deep doesn't work.

Comment: i can help if you can share a MVCE

Comment: What does MVCE stand for? Would you like to see the code?

Comment: I will try to prepare MVCE but later. I also tries to achieve the same effect using matNativeControl: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57249416/how-to-customize-mat-select-panel-with-matnativecontrol. Maybe you have an idea?