# Setting min-width of mat-select-panel leaves a visible animation in Angular 2+

Tags: css, angular, animation

I am trying to re-position a mat-select-panel, to be below the corresponding dropdown form-field. Using some of the code provided in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57246346/how-to-fix-position-of-mat-select-panel-in-angular-material), I have been able to do that. The problem is, that upon clicking, you can see the panel change size. This behaviour is visible in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-matselect-style-dwvyu8?file=src%2Fstyles.css) provided in the same question and accepted answer. So far I haven't been able to find a solution. 
Currently my .mat-select-panel in styles.css looks like this:

```
.mat-select-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 94px;
  left: 28px;
  min-width: calc(100% + 24px) !important;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  border-top-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> There is jump animation added to `<mat-select>` by angular
>   material, that's the reason it looks like width is increasing.

**Simple solution is to disable animation, but I could not find a solution to disable animation on specific element/component**

As said/discussed [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4227#issuecomment-348148642) and [here](https://angular.io/api/animations/trigger#disable-animations)

> To disable animation on **single elements** or **material components**

```
//TS  
isDisabled = true;

//HTML
<div [@.disabled]="isDisabled">
 <div [@childAnimation]="exp"></div>
</div>

<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
 <mat-select [@.disabled]="isDisabled" placeholder="Favorite food" disableOptionCentering>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
   {{food.viewValue}}
  </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**But unfortunately that doesn't work for `<mat-select>`**

> To disable animation for component

```
export class YourComponent {
 @HostBinding('@.disabled')
 public animationsDisabled = true;
}
```

**This doesn't work either.**

What works is ?

> Disabling animation for material cdk overlay (Include all material components) from component

```
import { Component, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { OverlayContainer } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
...
overlayContainerElement: HTMLElement
constructor( private overlayContainer:OverlayContainer, private renderer:Renderer2) {
    this.overlayContainerElement = this.overlayContainer.getContainerElement();
    //To disable pass true as third argument
    this.renderer.setProperty( this.overlayContainerElement, "@.disabled", true );
}
```

**Note:** The above code disables animation for whole application, if you want to disable animation for your specific component, simply add the above code in your component and add below code to re-enable animation.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
 this.renderer.setProperty( this.overlayContainerElement, "@.disabled", false );
}
```

> To disable animation for whole application

You can add the above code in main component (i.e., `app.component.ts`) or
**Replace `BrowserAnimationsModule` with `NoopAnimationsModule` in `app.module.ts`**

```
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
...
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ NoopAnimationsModule ],
  declarations: [ ... ],
  bootstrap:    [ ... ]
})
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-matselect-style-pzastt) (Animation disabled for component).